# BullMQ "error" event seems never triggered

Tags: bullmq

There is code using BullMQ and an 'error' event.
It seems never triggered.

```
const queue = new BullMQ.Queue(this.queueName, { connection });
queue.on('error', handleError);
queue.on('failed', handleJobError);
```

Is this event type exists in BullMQ?
It's not [in the BullMQ docs](https://docs.bullmq.io/guide/events) but it is in the [Bull docs](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/REFERENCE.md#events)

Comment: Facing the same issue

Comment: Seems like the `failed` doesn't exist for Queue. You have to listen for the `failed` event in the worker.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "error" event, but on Worker, not on Queue.
https://github.com/taskforcesh/bullmq/blob/master/docs/gitbook/api/bullmq.workerlistener.error.md

As far as I know, the "error" event on a Worker in BullMQ is generally used to handle uncaught exceptions that occur within the worker process itself, rather than handling errors that occur within a specific job.

Example: lost Redis connection